# You have the following class hierarchy

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, instance, subclass

```
class A(object): 
    def foo(self): 
        print 'hi'
class B(A): 
    def foo(self): 
        print 'bye'
```

Which of these statements are correct?

1. When `a = A()` we say that a is an instance of A
2. When `b = B()` we say that b is a subclass of A
3. Both of the above
4. Neither of the above

I believe that the answer is **B**.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking homework questions, in this format at least.

Comment: @francium  New to the site, won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class B inherits class A.

So class B is a subclass of A.

But when you instantiate A, `a = A()`, a is indeed an instance of A.

Now, I'm not sure about the wording, since, `b = B()`, is an instance of B... which is a subclass of A... but an instance is not a class or subclass. 
It is instead an instance of A... since B is child of A through inheritance.

So in summary, when you instantiate an object, it is a `instance` of the class and all of that classes parents. But an object is not a class.